# Как создать массив объектов из массивов

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста как создать массив из объектов. Вот пример

```js
var arrKeys = ['имя', 'любимый цвет', 'любимое блюдо'];
var arrArrs = [
  ['Василий'],
  ['Мария'],
  ['Иннокентий']
];


var getData = function(arrKeys, arrArrs){
  var newArr = []
  var customObject = new Object();
 
  console.log(customObject[arrKeys[0]] = arrArrs[0][0] )

  return newArr
  }
  
  console.log(getData(arrKeys, arrArrs))
```

Как мне в консоль получить массив который выглядел бы так 
[{'имя':'Василий'},{'имя':'Мария'},{'имя':'Иннокентий'}]

Что я делаю не так,почему мне в консоль возвращается значение первого ключа, а не ключ-значение ?

Comment: Вы имели ввиду как создать объект из массивов и занести его в массив, правильно? Просто у вас переменной вручную первый написан массив, а вторым массив из массивов

Comment: Мне надо массив, состоящий из объектов. Пример того что мне надо получить в консоль я написал. console.log(getData(arrKeys, arrArrs)) \*  [{'имя':'Василий'},{'имя':'Мария'},{'имя':'Иннокентий'}]

Comment: С вопросом что-то не так... для чего нужны "любимый цвет" и блюдо, если не используются? Или там в будущем будут массивы `["Василий", "Красный", "Спагетти"]` ?) Код от этого может отличаться.

Comment: Это часть от полной задачи. Мне б пока разобаться, как в консоль получить это значение.

Comment: Во-первых, лучше отформатируйте код. Во-вторых, вы никак не используете `newArr` в функции, потому логично, что всегда вернётся пустой массив. В третьих, зачем передавать весь массив, если вы использете только 1-й элемент? В четвертых, зачем создавать переменную вместо функции? В пятых, результат присваивания -- присвоенное значение, а не объект, у которого изменили поле. Потому и выводиться лишь имя.

Comment: Это очевидно тестовый пример, поэтому там много неоптимальностей. Но очевидно также и то, что функция возвращает пустой newArr, так как над ним не производится никаких действий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так я умею делать, а как задавать имя свойства в объекте через значение в arrKeys я не знаю и таким обычно не пользуются.

```js
let arrKeys = ['имя', 'любимый цвет', 'любимое блюдо'];
let arrArrs = [
  ['Василий'],
  ['Мария'],
  ['Иннокентий']
];

let customArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrArrs.length; i++) {
    let customObject = {
        имя: arrArrs[i][0]
    }
    customArr.push(customObject);
}

console.log(customArr);
```

**UPD:** нашёл решение, это синтаксис ES6, нужно просто указать имя свойства в `[]`

```js
let arrKeys = ['имя', 'любимый цвет', 'любимое блюдо'];
let arrArrs = [
  ['Василий'],
  ['Мария'],
  ['Иннокентий']
];

let customArr = () => {
    let massiv = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrArrs.length; i++) {
        let customObject = {
            [arrKeys[0]]: arrArrs[i][0]
        }

        massiv.push(customObject);
    }
    return massiv;
}

console.log(customArr());
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arrKeys = ['имя', 'любимый цвет', 'любимое блюдо'];
var arrArrs = [
  ['Василий'],
  ['Мария'],
  ['Иннокентий']
];

var getData = (arrKeys, arrArrs) => {
  return arrArrs.map(val => ({[arrKeys[0]] : val.toString()}));
}
  
console.log(getData(arrKeys, arrArrs));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы инициализируете customObject, а возвращаете пустой newArr

Надо так:

```
var arrKeys = ['имя', 'любимый цвет', 'любимое блюдо'];
var arrArrs = [
  ['Василий'],
  ['Мария'],
  ['Иннокентий']
];

var getData = function(arrKeys, arrArrs){
  var newArr = {}

  console.log(newArr[arrKeys[0]] = arrArrs[0][0] )

  return newArr
}

console.log(getData(arrKeys, arrArrs))
```